# Reading GPIO in bootloader

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, gpio, bootloader, bsp

I am running Windows CE on an IMx6 chip. I am trying to read button states during the bootloader stages to set the device to a different state.

Is there a GPIO library that I can generally call anywhere during bootloader?
I have been trying to call the functions in `common_ddk.h` (DDK = Device Driver kit) but I am getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no OS-Defined way to access GPIO in Windows CE. 
Every BSP can provide his own API/driver interface. Some do this by extending DDK, but there is no standard and, anyway, you will need different libraries (without any os-specific dependency like drivers or API calls) to access HW in the bootloader so, even if you have a solution for OS, that may not apply to the loader.
If you have the bootloader code you may check how GPIOs are accessed there, if you don't I would contact the vendor to check if they provide some ways to customize it or access to the code.

Comment: I did a direct register access with the use of INREG32(foo).

Comment: This is probably a good solution. If you have to just set a few parameters that should work and, being the bootloader single-core and single-thread, you'll probably don't have to manage any concurrent access issue.